# Implementar Colicion de elementos para juego en VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¡Buenas! ¿Me podrían ayudar con este problemilla que tengo? Relativamente soy nuevo en este foro y que descrubrí recientemente, estoy recreando el juego de "Arkanoid" o "Bricks" en lenguaje Visual Basic .NET. Pues resulta que tengo listo los ladrillos y las demás funcionalidades que respectan a la bola y la barra, ¿qué pasa? No sé como implementar lo demás que sería que la bola (PictureBox1) chocase con los ladrillos creados en la función "creacion_ladrillo()", ¿alguno sabe como hacerlo, como también lo que hay que tener en cuenta? Sólo necesito que la bola choque con los ladrillos y se "rompa" con cada uno y un mensaje que diga que ganó. Adjunto código:

````
    Dim posX, posY, L1, L2, L3, L4 As Integer
    Dim p1, p2, p3, p4 As Integer
    Dim crear_ladrillo As Label()
    Dim fila, columna As Integer
    Dim num_ladrillo As Integer


    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        PictureBox1.Left += posX
        PictureBox1.Top += posY
        ValidarLimite()
        ValidarChoque()
        ValidarChoqueLadrillo()

    End Sub

    Private Sub creacion_ladrillo()
        crear_ladrillo = New Label(40) {}
        num_ladrillo = 0
        posX = 120
        posY = 50

        For fila = 1 To 4
            posX = 100
            For columna = 1 To 10
                num_ladrillo = num_ladrillo + 1
                crear_ladrillo(num_ladrillo) = New Label()
                crear_ladrillo(num_ladrillo).Size = New Size(100, 60)
                crear_ladrillo(num_ladrillo).Location = New Point(posX, posY)
                crear_ladrillo(num_ladrillo).BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
                crear_ladrillo(num_ladrillo).BackColor = Color.DarkRed
                crear_ladrillo(num_ladrillo).Tag = "ladrillo"
                posX = posX + 120
                Me.Controls.Add(crear_ladrillo(num_ladrillo))
            Next
            posX = 70
            posY = posY + 100
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        creacion_ladrillo()
        Label2.Visible = False

        posX = 0
        posY = 50
        L1 = Label1.Left
        L2 = L1 + 300
        L3 = Label1.Top
        L4 = L3 + 80

        p1 = Label2.Left
        p2 = p1 + 100
        p3 = Label2.Top
        p4 = p3 + 30


        Timer1.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub ValidarChoqueLadrillo()

        If PictureBox1.Left > p1 And PictureBox1.Left < p2 Then
            If PictureBox1.Top > p3 And PictureBox1.Top < p4 Then
                posY = 50
                p1 = 0  ' izq
                p2 = 0   'Me.Width  ' derecha
                p3 = 0 ' arriba
                p4 = 0 ' Me.Height   ' abajo
            End If
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub ValidarChoque()
        If PictureBox1.Left > L1 And PictureBox1.Left < L2 Then
            If PictureBox1.Top + 32 > L3 And PictureBox1.Top < L4 Then

                'Rebota hacia la izquierda
                If PictureBox1.Left >= L1 And PictureBox1.Left <= L1 + 100 Then
                    posX = -50
                    posY = -50
                End If

                'Rebota hacia el medio
                If PictureBox1.Left >= L1 + 100 And PictureBox1.Left <= L1 + 200 Then
                    posX = 0
                    posY = -50
                End If

                'Rebota hacia la derecha
                If PictureBox1.Left >= L1 + 200 And PictureBox1.Left <= L1 + 300 Then
                    posX = 50
                    posY = -50
                End If

            End If
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub ValidarLimite()
        ' Abajo
        If Me.Controls.Find("PictureBox1", Enabled).First.Top + 70 > Me.Height Then
            posY = -50
            Timer1.Enabled = False
            MsgBox("¡Perdió!")
            End
        End If

        ' Derecha
        If Me.Controls.Find("PictureBox1", Enabled).First.Left + 40 > Me.Width Then
            posX = -50
        End If

        ' Arriba
        If Me.Controls.Find("PictureBox1", Enabled).First.Top < 5 Then
            posY = 50
        End If

        ' Izquierda
        If Me.Controls.Find("PictureBox1", Enabled).First.Left < 0 Then
            posX = 50
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
        Select Case e.KeyCode
            Case 37 'Izquierda
                Label1.Left += -50
                L1 -= 50
                L2 -= 50
            Case 39 'Derecha
                Label1.Left += 50
                L1 += 50
                L2 += 50
        End Select
    End Sub
End Class ```
````

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: ok, te comento... este sitio no es un foro. es un sitio de Q&A, preguntas y respuestas.

Comment: dices que no sabes como implementar el choque de los elementos... te puedo preguntar si has investigado eso mismo? o mejor dicho que has intentado?

Comment: relativamente hay muchas formas de hacerlo... y la idea es siempre la misma, detectar en que lugar esta la barra, la pelota y ladrillos... cuando la pelota llegue a la posicion de la barra cambias a direccion en el eje de la Y y cuando choca con un ladrillo cambia la direccion en el eje de las Y nuevamente y que el ladrillo debe desaparecer y debe dejar de ser detectado como obtaculo...

Comment: pero como te desia como hay tantas formas de hacerce tu pregunta entra en que esta basadas en opiniones por ende sera cerrada ... ahora si tienes codigo sobre esta idea y tienes un error de codigo especifico hay si podemos ayudarte.

Comment: La colision "pareceria" estar implementada.. cual seria el problema? no detecta que cosa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo creando un rectángulo, ya que esta estructura tiene una función para la intersección (IntersectsWith). Entonces la función ValidarChoqueLadrillo sería algo así:

```
Private Function ValidarChoqueLadrillo() As Integer

        Dim R1 As Rectangle = New Rectangle(PictureBox1.Location, PictureBox1.Size)

        For Index = 1 To 40
            Dim L = crear_ladrillo(Index)
            Dim R2 As Rectangle = New Rectangle(L.Location, L.Size)

            If L.Visible And R1.IntersectsWith(R2) Then
                Console.WriteLine("choque")

                'Efecto rebote
                If R2.Y + 60 <= R1.Y Then
                    posX = posX * -1
                Else
                    posY = posY * -1
                End If
                Return Index
            End If

        Next
        Return 0
    End Function
```

Retorna el número del ladrillo (del array) con que chocó. Si no ha chocado retorna cero